# Find text between two strings

Tags: python, regex

I've a big text like the following excerpt:

```
test = '''
Sra. Montero.- ¡No, no! No empecemos.   
Sr. Jefe de Gabinete de Ministros.- Respetuosamente se lo digo...   
Sra. Montero.- El senador Fernández
Sra. Montero.- ¡No, no! No empecemos.   
Sr. Jefe de Gabinete de Ministros.- Respetuosamente se lo digo...   
Sra. Montero.- El senador Fernández
Sra. Montero.- ¡No, no! No empecemos.   
Sr. Jefe de Gabinete de Ministros.- Respetuosamente se lo digo...   
Sra. Montero.- El senador Fernández
Sra. Montero.- ¡No, no! No empecemos.   
Sr. Jefe de Gabinete de Ministros.- Respetuosamente se lo digo...   
Sra. Montero.- El senador Fernández
'''
```

I'd like to get all the text between the string "Sr. Jefe de Gabinete de Ministros.-" and the string "Sr{{ random_text_here }}.-". So in this example what I'd like to get would be the following:

```
data = ['Respetuosamente se lo digo...', 'Respetuosamente se lo digo...', 'Respetuosamente se lo digo...']
```

I know the regex clause has to be non-greedy and I already tested something like this:

```
bw_sr = re.compile('\.\-(.+?)Sr[.+]\.\-') #non greedy regexx              
data = bw_sr.findall(test)
```

But I end up getting an empty list. I tried several clauses but I can't seem to get to a solution.

Comment: You're output data represents what comes immediately after each of those strings, not what comes between strings.

Answer (score 0):

your regex was wrong (this one `[.+]` was between brackets which defined a character range, so it wasn't working, among other issues, like no way to distinguish between "Sr." and "Sra" (seems what you wanted to do seeing the output), which I fixed by doing `Sr\.`).

I came up with that one which matches the formulas and also "El senador Fernández", etc... there's no criterion to filter those. I also added `\s*` before the capturing group to "strip" blanks:

```
bw_sr = re.compile('\.\-\s*(.+?)\nSr\..+?\.\-')
data = bw_sr.findall(test)

print(data)
```

result:

```
['¡No, no! No empecemos.', '¡No, no! No empecemos.', '¡No, no! No empecemos.', '¡No, no! No empecemos.']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work:

```
bw_sr = re.compile('\.\- (.*)')
data = bw_sr.findall(test)
```